# Как подключить устройство для отладки в Андроид студио без USB

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка

Есть аппарат на ОС Андроид 4.4.  USB порта нет, есть только wifi, как его подключить к  Android Studio ?

Answer (score 3):

Если на устройстве есть root-права, то можно разрешить отладку через Wi-Fi с помощью следующих команд:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

И отключить с использованием команд

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
stop adbd
start adbd
```

В противном случае, при первом использовании устройства для отладки потребуется подключение через USB. Основные шаги:

1. Подключить компьютер и мобильное устройство к одной Wi-Fi сети;
2. Подключить мобильное устройство к компьютеру через USB;
3. Выполнить команду `adb tcpip 5555`;
4. Отсоединить кабель;
5. Подключиться к устройству, используя его IP-адрес командой `adb connect ip_адрес_устройства`.

[Ответ на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp/3623727)

[Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless)

---

Также непродолжительный поиск [показал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi), что на **некоторых** устройствах в разделе меню `Developer options` есть настройка

[image: ADB over network]

Если это так, то нужно включить её и выполнить команду `adb connect ip_адрес_устройства:5555`.

Comment: В доках написано: но вы также можете использовать adb через Wi-Fi после некоторой начальной настройки через USB. Т.е. получается, что usb всё равно нужен. Я полагаю что без USB это не возможно.

Comment: Что касается второго случая - да, USB все равно нужен. Насколько мне известно, чтобы начать отладку вообще без USB, нужны root-права, и без них никак.

Comment: Хм... Ну может. У меня телефон не рутованый, пробовать не буду.

Comment: Попробовал запустить приложение из adb на смартфоне через WiFi. Вроде всё пошло, но затем выдало ошибку com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
Error while Installing APK. Возможно это связано с тем, что у меня нет вышеозначенной настройки "ADB over network".

Comment: Настройка "ADB over network" - это очень частный случай. Например, она есть в CyanogenMod, LineageOS и др. Если ее нет и нет root-прав, то нужно использовать второй способ - подключение посредством USB.

Comment: ...................................ok